# R packages available tab shows up when rmarkdown complies

Tags: r, rstudio

Every time I compile a Rmarkdown file this tab pops up on in Rstudio. The tab is "R packages available". How do I stop this tab from appearing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Calling the function library() with no parameters will cause this.